# Spray Json Deserialize Root Sequence

Tags: spray-json

I want to deserialize a Json string which is a sequence at the root node. For example,

```
[{"name":"Bob", "age":26}, {"name":"Ted", "age":24}]
```

How do I use spray-json to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked my unmarshaller to unmarshal the string as a Seq like -

```
unmarshal[Seq[Person]]
```

and it worked.